# Data Binding Many to Many in Entity Framework Core MVC App

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble binding data from a connected table in my controller. How do I ensure with the following setup that Tags are bound to Product, so in my controller Product.Tags is not null? My code is below and this generates a connecting table in SQL so I have tables for Product, ProductTag, and Tag.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
 
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 

    public Product()
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public Tag()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }
}

public class ProductFormViewModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

If I write out the Product.Tags in my view like this:

```
@if (Model.Product.Tags != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Product.Tags.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Product.Tags.ToArray()[i].TagId)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Product.Tags.ToArray()[i].Name);
    }
}
```

then in my controller, Tags has the values bound, but model.Products.Tags is null and ideally I just want to maintain or update the values in model.Product.Tags and not require an additional list of Tags as per below. However, nothing I try is binding:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, ProductFormViewModel model, List<Tag> Tags)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Html.TextBox instead of @Html.TextBoxFor and override the name attribute.

```
@if (Model.Product.Tags != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Product.Tags.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBox("Product.Tags[" + i + "].TagID", Model.Product.Tags.ToArray()[i].TagID)
        @Html.TextBox("Product.Tags[" + i + "].Name", Model.Product.Tags.ToArray()[i].Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a special viewmodel. In your  case you can use this code for model

```
var model=context.Set<Product>().Include(t=> t.Tags).FirstOrDefault(i=> i.ID==productId);
```

and by the way you don't need to convert tags to array

```
@model Product
.......

 for (var i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tags[i].TagId)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tags[i].Name);
    }
```

You have to fix the action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Product model)
{
var id=model.ID;
var tags=model.Tags;
.....
```

Comment: Thanks. I have similar in my controller and have no problem with the binding when loading my Edit page if that's where you mean? However, the problem is the binding when clicking Save on that page - model.Product.Tags is null

Comment: I need to see the whole view and  how  you submit your form after edit

Comment: I use a custom view model as there are other properties which I've left off here to keep the code more simple. With the custom view model Tags is null, however, without a custom view model, Tags. Count is zero so that's progress. So how can I bind the Tags to the model as where you suggest var tags=model.Tags, Tags.Count is zero which is incorrect.

Comment: Did you use my query?

Comment: I need to see how are trying to submit. I need the whole view.

Comment: I've posted all here so hopefully that helps. Thank you! https://dotnetfiddle.net/fVId5N

Comment: Thanks, as it is in my answer try to replace      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Tags.ToArray()[i].TagId) with      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Tags[i].TagId) and the same with name.

Comment: And just by the way instead of asp-for="@Model.Name"  you  can use asp-for="Name"   and so on

Comment: I updated my answer. Try to use   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tags[i].TagId)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately without the ToArray() it says 'Cannot apply indexing [] to an expression of type 'ICollection<Tag>'' and still get the binding problem this way.